# i want to insert human in gazebo for implementing computer vision

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm working on disaster robotics which is going to be simulated in gazebo enviroment ,so am wondering if it is possible to insert human in to the enviroment so that implementing computer vision algorithms to find victim when the robot maneuver around. i have created enviroment using build editor but i don't know if it is possible to create human (victim) posture in the environment.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/22661/i-want-to-insert-human-in-gazebo-for-implementing--computer-vision/) by [Abraham](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8542/abraham/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-05-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on 2019-05-28**:
There is a model of a human in the default gazebosim library at models.gazebosim.org. `person_walking` and `person_standing`.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2019-05-28**:
There are also a couple of "survivor" models here: https://app.ignitionrobotics.org/search;q=survivor

**Comment by [Abraham](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8542/abraham/) on 2019-06-19**:
Thank you both ,this what i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

On the comments above, @kumpakri suggested `person_walking` and `person_standing` from models.gazebosim.org, and I suggested the survivor models from https://app.ignitionrobotics.org/search;q=survivor.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2019-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abraham](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8542/abraham/) on 2019-06-26**:
Thank you very much